# Using openpyxl to append URL links to Excel, but they aren't hyperlinked in Excel

Tags: python, excel, append, openpyxl

I've been using openpyxl's append() function to add url links to an Excel document. When I open Excel, none of the links have hyperlinks until I go into each individual cell and press enter. How do I format as hyperlink via Python during my append? Thanks!

```
url = 'www.google.com'
ws.append([url])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the cell hyperlink attribute and the style. Then Excel doesn't need to work it out, which is what happens when you select the cell and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Here's a minimal example:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()  # create a new workbook
ws = wb.active  # get the active sheet

ws.title = "Hyperlink Test"

# write to the first cell
cell = ws.cell(column=1, row=1, value="Google")
cell.hyperlink = "https://www.google.com"
cell.style = "Hyperlink"

output_name = "test_hyperink.xlsx"
wb.save(output_name)
```